# Error while installing ruby GTK2 on mac os x

Tags: ruby, gtk2

I'm trying to install the gtk2 gem on my system, but I'm getting this error:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Mateus:~ mateusgomesfreitas$ gem install gtk2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gtk2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mateusgomesfreitas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for GCC... yes
checking for rb_define_alloc_func() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_block_proc() in ruby.h... yes
checking for new allocation framework... yes
checking for attribute assignment... no
checking for Win32 OS... no
checking for gobject-2.0... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/mateusgomesfreitas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-override-variables
    --without-override-variables


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mateusgomesfreitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-    p290/gems/glib2-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mateusgomesfreitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/glib2-1.0.3/ext/glib2/gem_make.out
```

---

here is my gemlist:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.10)
actionpack (3.0.10)
activemodel (3.0.10)
activerecord (3.0.10)
activeresource (3.0.10)
activesupport (3.0.10)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.18)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql2 (0.3.7, 0.2.13)
pkg-config (1.1.2)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.2.4, 1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.10)
railties (3.0.10)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rubygems-update (1.8.10)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
```

and my ruby version:
    ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.1]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have GTK installed? The `checking for gobject-2.0... no` indicates that you don't have glib (which, AFAIK, GTK needs).

Comment: I've downloaded the gtk+ from http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php with git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtk+ and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you compile and install it? [Brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) is probably your best bet for this sort of thing, once that's there you could `brew install gtk+` and that should sort things out.

Answer (score 0):

@mu-is-too-short is spot on

install gtk+ using `brew install gtk+`